# MySQL - Match with min. number in a range - improve join performance with order by and group

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have 2 tables. One that contains stock information with a timestamp, price, ticker_id.

```
CREATE TABLE `data_realtime` ( 
 `id` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `timestamp` int(10) NOT NULL, 
 `ticker_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL, 
 `price` decimal(7,2) unsigned NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
 UNIQUE KEY `ticker_timestamp` (`ticker_id`,`timestamp`) USING BTREE, 
 CONSTRAINT `data_realtime_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ticker_id`) REFERENCES 
 `tickers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1585421 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And the other contains ticker info with ticker_id and name. (However I don't think this is relevant here)

```
CREATE TABLE `tickers` ( 
 `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `ticker` text NOT NULL, 
 `ticker_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
 UNIQUE KEY `ticker` (`ticker`(5)) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9416 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I run a query that gets the latest rows for each ticker (using ticker_id).

```
SELECT ticker_id, max(timestamp) max_timestamp FROM `data_realtime` GROUP BY ticker_id
```

I want to then get the corresponding stock price, 3 minutes ago.
I do this by joining the initial result (latest prices) with all rows newer than 3 mins; then ordering by them by the timestamp; then grouping them by ticker_id.

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM (  
    SELECT  
    data_latest.*, data_3m.timestamp timestamp_3m, data_3m.price price_3m 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT B.* FROM ( 
            SELECT  
            ticker_id, max(timestamp) max_timestamp  
            FROM  
            `data_realtime`  
            GROUP BY ticker_id)  
        A  
        LEFT JOIN  
        data_realtime B  
        ON A.ticker_id=B.ticker_id and A.max_timestamp=B.timestamp)  
    data_latest  
    LEFT JOIN  
    data_realtime data_3m  
    ON  
    data_latest.timestamp <= (data_3m.timestamp + (60*3) )  
    AND  
    data_latest.timestamp>data_3m.timestamp  
    AND  
    data_latest.ticker_id=data_3m.ticker_id  
    ORDER BY  
    data_3m.timestamp ASC)  
data_3m_sorted 
GROUP BY ticker_id
```

As you can see from the Create Table, there exists a primary key on 'id' and a combined unique key on 'timestamp' and 'ticker'.

The query takes a little over 2 secs to run with about 1.5M rows in the table. Is there anything I can do to improve the query performance.

Will adding single indexes on ticker_id and timestamp column help? If so, why?

Thanks for the help.